# Android: Quickblox Client is not, or no longer, connected. error

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I use Quickblox for chat room

My code:

```
final QBChatDialog dialog = DialogUtils.buildPrivateDialog(id);
dialog.setType(QBDialogType.PRIVATE);

QBRestChatService.createChatDialog(dialog).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog result, Bundle params) {
        try {
            QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
            chatMessage.setBody("Hi there!");
            dialog.sendMessage(chatMessage);
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            Log.i("errorCheck", "Chat: NO : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {
        Log.i("errorCheck", "Chat: FAIL" + responseException.getMessage());
    }
});
```

I get this error :

> Client is not, or no longer, connected. error

But I'm sure my client is connected

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Have you solved this problem

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following before sending message:

```java
qbChatDialog.initForChat(QBChatService.getInstance());
```